# Text-to-MP3 Not Working with Longer Strings

Tags: mysql, node.js, mp3

My node.js program is designed to create MP3 files that correspond to text strings in a MySQL database. I'm using the text-to-mp3 module to do this. It's working great, except some of my files are empty (0 bytes). I've noticed that t**his is only happening when the text string is longer** -- like three or four sentences.

Any advice? I'm wondering if it has to do with the `binaryStream` argument. Can I change this? If so, how?

```
txtomp3.getMp3(mystring, function(err, binaryStream){
  if(err){
    console.log(err);
    return;
  }


function writeit() {
  var file = fs.createWriteStream("myverse.mp3");
  console.log('recording the verse')
  file.write(binaryStream);
  file.end();
}
```

Comment: yep, you are right when string is longer than LIMITED characters it return 0 bytes. And `text-to-mp3` says `#Text to MP3 This is a Simple script to generate MP3 from text, using public Google Translate API, so it have the limits of public usage`

Comment: I read elsewhere that the Google translate API has a limit of 5000 characters per request. None of my strings are that long.

Comment: Google Text-To-Speech API (for free) can not deal with texts which are over than 200 characters.

Comment: Is it possible to update the text-to-mp3 module to use my paid api?

Comment: Nevermind. I ended up using Amazon Polly instead.